# Please help me with resizing and flexible scaling of my pages

Tags: html, css, resize, scale, scalability

I'm racking my brain over here, trying to find a way for my divs to stay together when page re-sizing happens. (I made all the colored lines on the page as divs, except for the two vertical and the long horizontal on bottom. That's part of a border). Also for the Title/Menu/Rest-of-the-page to stay cohesive.

A step-by-step would be very appreciated, as I'm kinda new to html and css, and my site is live. You can check it out for hands-on (instead of combing through the code/css I pasted) at http://www.yamatat.com

I'm trying to make the default size at 1366 x 768, as that's that size has the most global share right now.

Here's my html:

```
    <title>You And Me And Thoughts And Talk with Doug Culp</title>
</head>
<div class="page-title-container">
    <div id="orangeone"></div>
    <div id="blueone"></div>
    <div class="page-title">YOU AND ME AND THOUGHTS AND TALK WITH DOUG CULP</div>
    <div id="orangetwo"></div>
    <div id="bluetwo"></div>
    <div id="bluethree"></div>
    <div id="bluefour"></div>
    <div id="bluefive"></div>
    <nav>
        <a id="home" class="menu" href="http://www.yamatat.com/index.html">HOME</a>
        <a id="podcast" class="menu" href="http://www.yamatat.com/podcast.html">PODCAST</a>
        <a id="media" class="menu" href="http://www.yamatat.com/media.html">MEDIA</a>
        <a id="blog" class="menu" href="http://www.yamatat.com/blog.html">BLOG</a>
        <a id="shows" class="menu" href="http://www.yamatat.com/shows.html">SHOWS</a>
    </nav>
</div>

<body>
    <h1 class="home_news"><span>NEWS STUFF//</span></h1>
    <div id="underline_news"></div>
    <div id="news"><span id="news_date">12/24/2013</span>
        <p>It's been a wild ride so far. I'm writing this before the site goes live. You guys don't even know!! I learned how to make my own page so that I could make it and put it out for you guys, the listeners. The YAMATATers. Scalloped, baked, french
            fried. Any way you want it, THAT's the way you need it. It's 5:20 am. I should really get to bed. Merry Christmas Eve everyone!!</p>
    </div>
    <a class="twitter-timeline" width="400" height="450" data-dnt="true" href="https://twitter.com/dougathan" data-widget-id="416479074542817280">Tweets by @dougathan</a>
    <script>
        ! function (d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
                p = /^http:/.test(d.location) ? 'http' : 'https';
            if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
                js = d.createElement(s);
                js.id = id;
                js.src = p + "://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }
        }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs");
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

And here's my css:

```
.page-title-container {
    min-width: 85.375em;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 60px;
    color: #00BFFF;
    text-align: center;
    border-width: 10px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin-left: 45px;
    margin-right: 45px;
    font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: -20px;
}

.page-title {
    font-size: 60px;
    color: #00BFFF;
    text-align: center;
    border-width: 10px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin-left: 238px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
    padding-bottom: -10px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    margin-top: -64px;
    border-style: solid solid solid solid;
    border-color: orange;
    width: 1410px;
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 55px;
}

a.menu:hover {
    color: orange;
}

a:hover {
    color: orange;
}

a:hover .body_link {
    color: orange;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#orangeone {
    height: 10px;
    width: 255px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: orange;
    float: left;
    margin-left: -8px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    position: relative;
}

#orangetwo {
    height: 10px;
    width: 255px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: orange;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-top: -61px;
    position: relative;
}

#orangethree {
    height: 62px;
    width: 10px;
    background-color: orange;
    float: left;
    margin-left: -5px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    position: relative;
}

#orangefour {
    height: 62px;
    width: 10px;
    background-color: orange;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    position: relative;
}

#orangefive {
    height: 10px;
    width: 1423px;
    background-color: orange;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 240px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    position: relative;
}

#blueone {
    height: 10px;
    width: 240px;
    background-color: #00bfff;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin-left: -8px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    position: relative;
}

#bluetwo {
    height: 10px;
    width: 245px;
    background-color: #00bfff;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-top: -46px;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
}

#bluethree {
    height: 100px;
    width: 10px;
    background-color: #00bfff;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 222px;
    margin-top: -40px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    position: relative;
}

#bluefour {
    height: 100px;
    width: 10px;
    background-color: #00bfff;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 235px;
    margin-top: -40px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    position: relative;
}

#bluefive {
    height: 10px;
    width: 1460px;
    background-color: #00bfff;
    float: center;
    margin-left: 223px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin-top: 87px;
    position: relative;
}

a.menu {
    text-decoration: none;
    float: top;
    font-size: 46px;
    color: black;
    position: absolute;
    font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

#home {
    margin-top: -66px;
    margin-left: 400px;
}

#podcast {
    margin-top: -66px;
    margin-left: 600px;
}

#media {
    margin-top: -66px;
    margin-left: 890px;
}

#blog {
    margin-top: -66px;
    margin-left: 1125px;
}

#shows {
    margin-top: -66px;
    margin-left: 1350px;
}

.home_news, .home_pod {
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 55px;
    color: black;
    margin-top: 25px;
    border-bottom: solid 10px black;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline;
    border-radius: 0px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 40px;
}

.home_news span {
    position: relative;
    top: 12px;
}

.home_pod span {
    position: relative;
    top: 12px;
}

#news_date {
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

#news {
    float: left;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-top: 105px;
    width: 650px;
    white-space: normal;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

.home_pod {
    position: relative;
    top: 12px;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 55px;
    color: black;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 40px;
}

#pod_date {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 30px;
}

#pod {
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-top: 105px;
    width: 650px;
    white-space: normal;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    margin-left: 45px;
}

.twitter-timeline {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 25px;
}

a#Eegg_1 {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 35px;
    margin-top: -110px;
}

#Eegg_1_expl {
    float: left;
    color: black;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 155px;
    margin-left: -287px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

a#youtube_link {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 210px;
    margin-top: -5px;
}

a:hover #youtube_small {
    float: right;
}

#bloggy_head {
    float: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 800px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

#bloggy_doit {
    float: left;
    font-family: Courier;
    font-size: 70px;
    margin-left: 745px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.body_link {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.home_shows {
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 55px;
    color: black;
    margin-top: 25px;
    float: left;
}

#underline_shows {
    height: 10px;
    width: 275px;
    background-color: black;
    float: left;
    margin-left: -323px;
    margin-top: 85px;
}

#show_calendar {
    float: left;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-left: -320px;
    margin-top: 105px;
    width: 650px;
    white-space: normal;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: *All* of this code is required to reproduce your problem?  That's a lot to go through.

Comment: @cimmanon Good point, sorry. I took some out of the html and the css. Still new, so I don't wanna take anything out that would possibly have to be wrapped or something like that.

Comment: Which exact Problem do you want to tackle? a complete redesign, only the navigation, some special div's? (btw. i just checked out your page with my netbook win7 chrome 31+ resolution 1366*768 in a maximized window and i cant see the whole title.)

Comment: @winner_joiner I want the page to be centered while at 1366 x 768, and to scale up and down without breaking in the resizing process

Comment: honestly I would recommend a framework like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/). it is abit of an overhead to learn(i think its pretty easy), but you dont have to worry about resizing issues.

Comment: @winner_joiner Would I get BootStrap and Source? And then what would I do? Do I need to change any of the code I've put already, or would I put it as a framework and it would work around my mistakes?

Comment: @cimmanon Is there an easy fix to make everything scale-able, something that could keep everything together and centered no matter the size of the page/screen that's opening the page? All of the orange and blue lines are divs, except for the two vertical orange and the really long orange. Those are part of a border I set up with a specific line-height.

Comment: There's no easy fix for this. Using a framework won't automagically turn your existing non-responsive code into a beautiful flowing responsive site. You need to rebuild it either way. A framework will teach you how to use % based designs, grids, and media queries. All of which are important in responsive design, and all of which you have not utilised in your design. If I were you, I'd start from scratch with responsive in mind (instead of trying to add it as an afterthought).

Comment: @ChristianVarga I understand that I'll have to change a lot, or even completely start from scratch. Can you point me to some articles that teach me responsive design so that I can have something to work with? Thanks in advance. I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this much simpler with a bookend design using images.

For example:

[Bookend Left Image][Title + Nav Div with flexible width and background][Bookend Right Image]

Comment: I wouldn't know how to do something like that. Still pretty new at this. Learning online and getting help here and there.